# Unreadable lozenge characters in tty1

Tags: debian, console, tty, locale, character-encoding

Something wrong is going on in my Debian Jessie. Usually I use tty7 with GUI and everything is fine here. In tty1 though, Polish characters (both being typed and read from UTF-8 files) are represented by vertical diamonds, or lozenges. Similar to this one only all white (on black background).

```
◊
```

My locale looks fine, I gather.

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

They are the same in the GUI on tty7, and all's fine here. To the best of my knowledge and experience, tty1 should work. But it doesn't. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*GUI on `tty7`* uses X fonts, while `tty1` uses Linux console fonts (with a limit of 512 different glyphs).  The Linux console is showing those lozenges (depending on the font) where a Unicode *replacement character* would be displayed because the code it is trying to display is not legal UTF-8.

You would get that behavior for ISO-8859-1, etc.  You may recall that ISO-8859-1 codes **`0xa0`** to **`0xff`** map to Unicode **`0x00a0`** to **`0x00ff`**.  But in UTF-8, the bytes look different.

"Typing" the file (perhaps with `cat`) is unaffected by the locale.  The *encoding* of the data and the *mode* (UTF-8 or not) of the terminal determines whether the character prints normally.

One interesting (mis)feature of [rxvt-unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rxvt-unicode) is that it notices non-UTF-8 data and helpfully assumes that it was ISO-8859-1 and (silently) converts it to Unicode.  Polish would be ISO-8859-2, which looks mostly the same

If you happen to be using rxvt-unicode and examining non-UTF8 Polish text, that would explain all of the symptoms in the question.

The `file` utility could make a reasonable guess whether the text is UTF-8 or not.

Following up on clarification, here are a few screenshots to show what you *can* get from the default font in Linux console.  This uses the [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) test-program, displaying more/less the codes 0-255:

First, the Latin-1 characters with UTF-8 mode:

[image: Latin-1 coverage with UTF-8]

Then the Latin-1 characters *without* UTF-8 mode:

[image: Latin-1 coverage without UTF-8]

And using UTF-8 mode, but running [`luit`](http://invisible-island.net/luit/) with ISO8859-2 encoding, and the same test-program using `pl_PL` (a little roundabout, but something you can compare with):

[image: Latin-2 coverage using <code>luit</code>]

and compare that with [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html):

[image: Latin-2 coverage using <code>xterm</code>]

In summary, you may notice some lozenges for the **Latin-1** character set using the limited fonts for UTF-8 mode in the Linux console.  But Polish (a different character set) appears to be well covered.

Comment: I thought the texts I displayed were in UTF-8. I made the files using the console. Shouldn't it use UTF? I still don't get it. I was ok in Ubuntu, which I abandoned a month ago.

Comment: Re your update. `file` says the file I'm using for testing is `UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines`. It displays ok in GUI, but with lozenges in `tty1`.

Comment: If the text is **Polish**, odds are that all of the glyphs are in the set of 512 provided in the console font.  If not, it depends.  We don't have a view of the working version, can only use the information in the question.